# jQuery if checkbox is checked malfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit strange problem, I have a form with a checkbox, where Jquery has to adjust values in an input field. But, when I check with `console.log($('#praktijk').is(':checked'));` I get a neat true or false answer, no problem there.
But when I put it in an if statement like this `$('#praktijk').is(':checked')` it doesn't work, for some vague reason.
For more interpretation I'll give the whole jscript code:

```
$('#praktijk').on('change', function() {
        let a = $('input[name="aantal"]').val() * $('input[name="lesprijs"]').val();
        var checked = $('#praktijk').is(':checked');
        console.log($('#praktijk').is(':checked'));
        if ($('#praktijk').is(':checked')) {
            let b = Number($('input[name="examenprijs"]').val());
        } else {
            let b = 0;
        }
        let prijs = a + b;
        $('input[name="pakketprijs"]').val(prijs);
    });
```

I'm really confused about this, and hope someone can help me.
Grts

Comment: *it doesn't work* - it works fine.  The problem is how you are checking if it "worked".  You're checking by seeing if `a` and `b` have been added together.  The answers show that issue.   This comment is to say that you should restrict your "does it work" to the **part that you're checking**, not the overall end result - ie just the `if (..cheched..)` - add a `console.log("checked")` *inside* the `if`, before `let b = Number..` and a `console.log("not checked")` *inside` the `else`, before `let b = 0` - or use breakpoints of course - and you'll see that the `if` part is working fine.

Comment: What none of the existing answers mentions is that `a+b` still works, because the `b` at this point becomes an **implied global variable**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a variable inside an *if* or *else* block using `let`, it is only accessible within that block. In your code, you are declaring `b` inside the *if* and *else* blocks, and trying to use it outside those blocks.

```
...
let b = 0; // Declare b outside the if-else block

if ($('#praktijk').is(':checked')) {
    b = Number($('input[name="examenprijs"]').val());
}

let prijs = a + b;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `b` variable out of the if.

This is the corrected code:

```js
$('#praktijk').on('change', function() {
        let a = $('input[name="aantal"]').val() * $('input[name="lesprijs"]').val();
        var checked = $('#praktijk').is(':checked');
        console.log($('#praktijk').is(':checked'));
        let b = 0;
        if ($('#praktijk').is(':checked')) {
            b = Number($('input[name="examenprijs"]').val());
        }
        let prijs = a + b;
        $('input[name="pakketprijs"]').val(prijs);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are declaring 'b' variable inside the if block and trying to access it outside.

Declare the variable before if as,

```
 let b = 0;
```

Ex.,

```
 $('#praktijk').on('change', function() {
            let a = $('input[name="aantal"]').val() * $('input[name="lesprijs"]').val();
            let b = 0;
            var checked = $('#praktijk').is(':checked');
            console.log($('#praktijk').is(':checked'));                
            if ($('#praktijk').is(':checked')) {
                b = Number($('input[name="examenprijs"]').val());
            }  
            let prijs = a + b;
            $('input[name="pakketprijs"]').val(prijs);
        });
```